# Concatenate multiple text files if order of filename, from a command prompt?

Tags: command-line

I used to be able to concatenate multiple text files in dos command by order of filename by using this command:

```
FOR %%1 in (1*.txt) do type %%1 >> combined.txt
```

Problem is the text files are not combined by the filename order anymore not sure why. So instead of File1.txt, File2.txt and File3.txt they are in order of File3.txt, File1.txt and File2.txt. 
Any help would be great!

Comment: Does it have to be command prompt, or do you have access to PowerShell?

Comment: When you say "used to" - when was that?  I don't believe DOS/Windows guarantees the return order of directory entries.

Answer (score 1):

I too would do this in Powershell in 2016, but this seems to work

`for %i in (1*.txt) do echo %i|sort|type %I >combined.txt`

(Add second % for use in script file)

Comment: That works until you have 10 files :)

Comment: I don't think that's an issue since he said the files start with `1*`. 1 would come first, then 10, 11, 12, etc